# Saying bracha on dairy product before 6 hours have run?

Tags: blessing, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Is there an accepted practice on what you are supposed to do if you thought 6 hours had run and say a bracha on a glass of milk but then you realize right before drinking it that it has not been 6 hours and you were confused?  Should you drink it or not drink it and the bracha was said but not needed?  Does the amount of time that has lapsed matter?